# Получение постов twitter от страниц на которые подписан пользователь

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, twitter, twitter-api

С помощью такого кода я получаю список постов пользователя (его твитты):

```
public void getwalltw(){
    final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
            .build();
    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new   TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTimeline(userTimeline)
            .build();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Есть что-нибудь в этом роде, что бы получить список твиттов, от страниц на которые подписан пользователь? То есть, то что мы видим, когда заходим на вкладку "Главная" в твиттере. Спасибо.

Comment: Неужели в документации Twitter API нет этого?

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста найти )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю [это](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline) то что вы ищите. На будующее, если не знаете английского, вбивайте в поиск ключевые слова соответсвующие вашему запросу. Чтобы найти эту документацию достаточно вбить **twitter api get feed**.

Comment: usertimeline возвращает только посты пользователя, а как вот feed получить. Можете показать мне ?

Comment: Поменял ссылку. Я думаю это самое близкое к тому что вы хотите.

Comment: Да, думаю мне это подойдет, спасибо !